# How to modify the existing solution ODOO-11 Production module for its automatic operation in restaurant accounting

Tags: odoo-11

The problem I have is that the production function in ODOO 11 cannot be applied in a catering establishment. I did not find there a procedure for automatically writing off ingredients for production. Can someone tell me where to look for a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi there! Please provide more detail to help the viewers clearly understand the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I have clarified.

Answer (score 0):

How does the ODOO Production section work? A bill of materials is created for the product, then the Technological map is issued.
A production order that is running up to the status Done. This way you can only perform transactions in the engineering production.
Imagine now the flow of products in the Restaurant. How can one interpret with such performing instruments production of products?
We need others who would allow, upon the fact of registration of the sale of products in the restaurant, automatically write off the
ingredients used for its production. Otherwise, it is not possible to catch up with this stream.
Maybe there is such a method, but I did not find it. There may be functionally similar modules, but I don't know anything about them.
I decided to clarify this information before starting to write something like that:)